# Add a view inside an existing schema (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, view, schema

how can I add 1 or more views to an existing schema without having to create the schema from scratch?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create view using below syntax

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW <schemaname>.<viewname> AS 
SELECT *
    FROM tablename
    WHERE col = 'condition';
```

this will create a view in that specific schema.

Please be more elaborative with your questions so that I can help you